# Testcafe issues with OKTA OAuth login page

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We use OKTA to login to our portal. Users visit our website page, where they click Login, then we redirect them to OKTA login page. Once they enter the credentials and authenticate themselves we redirect users to our portal home page. For some reason Testcafe fails the test as in it cannot find the HTML element after the login. I can see the running test enter credentials but does not navigate to our portal home page. This is not the experience when I browse myself. Is there some additional settings for OAuth?

```
let testURL:string = 'https://mysite/home';

const myUserRole = Role('https://mysite/login', async t => {
    await t
    .click(Selector('#btnLogin')) // click on the login link , takes to OKTA login page
    .typeText(Selector('#okta-signin-username'),"username")
    .typeText(Selector('#okta-signin-password'),"password")
    .click(Selector('#okta-signin-submit'));
});

fixture('Test1')
.page(testURL)
test('Create new records', async t => {

    await t
    .useRole(myUserRole)    // the login process
    .click(Selector('#myelement'));   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< cannot find this element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user role mechanism is used, TestCafe navigates back to the page that was opened before the role was switched. To change this behavior, set the [preserveUrl](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/role/constructor.html#optionspreserveurl) option to `true`.

Comment: I have tried it but it takes to back to login page, as if I never logged in.

Comment: One more possible cause can be the browser's page caching. Navigate to the following troubleshooting guide: [Test Actions Fail After Authentication](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html#test-actions-fail-after-authentication). If that doesn't help either, please [submit](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) a bug report with a reproducible example.

Comment: I have tried all the page caching options but unfortunately it didn't help me. I think going forward many organizations will adopt OAuth login scenarios and I feel it would help TestCafe's adoption

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with oAuth.

```
node --max-http-header-size=1024000 ./node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js chrome <your script>
```

this solved it for me. Try running your test like this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It works like this, but I am wondering why not with the regular testcafe way?

Comment: TestCafe sets the default maximum header size of 80KB. If a header exceeds this limit, TestCafe should display an error message that asks you to increase the limit.
 
If you do not see an error message, ensure you run the latest TestCafe version. If so, please [create a bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) on GitHub with a reproducible example where this error is not displayed.